# How to avoid android appcompat v7 error?

Tags: android

1.Every new project created `appcompat v7` project included in project explorer.

2.I cannot create `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

3.If I create this error is shown.

Comment: create a project without ticking CREATE ACTIVITY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let Eclipse create Activity. Do it yourself. 
Untick "Create Activity" option when creating new project.

Comment: What you need to do is: Create Project>Untick "Create Activity" Feature, then create package in Src folder. Then just create activity in that package. That is how I did it and it worked for me.